# How to import text file with sessions (that I have earlier exported) into fiddler?

Tags: fiddler

I have exported around 100 sessions from fiddler into text file like, `File` -> `Export Sessions` -> `Selected sessions` -> `Raw files`

Now I have a file that is 15MB and holds information with requests and responses that are separated by a line of dashes (`----------------------------------`).

**How do I import these sessions back into fiddler?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Export Sessions > Raw Files doesn't do that-- it exports the HTTP response bodies as individual flat files, dropping all headers and requests entirely.

If you chose File > Save Selected Sessions > As Text, you'll end up with a text file in the format you describe. You cannot, generally speaking, reimport such files into Fiddler because text is a lossy format.

If you want to keep traffic for reloading in Fiddler, the default Session Archive Zip format is your best bet, although export/import of HAR format is only somewhat more lossy.